# How can I add getter and setter to PropertyDeclarationSyntax?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm creating a tool which can create properties through Roslyn. I would like to add getter and setters to a `PropertyDeclarationSyntax`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add an `AccessorList`, with accessors. Check out this online tool for the exact syntax tree creation: [Roslyn Quoter](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/).

Comment: Whoa, that tool is so nice!

Comment: Good tool to explore Syntax Tree for C#